# How to add primary/foreign keys in SQLAlchemy Python?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

This is my code:

```
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype={
            'PassengerId':Integer(),
            'Name': String(length=255),
            'Age': Float(),
            'Sex': String(length=10),
        }, constraint=[PrimaryKeyConstraint('PassengerId')])
        print(f"Table '{table_name}' created successfully!")
```

I"m trying to convert my `dataframe` into a table and add constraints like primary key, foreign key etc.

Could you please tell me how to add these constraints, and also add foreign keys?